# Adding force to a sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

i have a 2d character and i want to make its head pop off.

Add force seems the most logical but i cannot get any force and it also must depend on the characters rotation. So if hes laying sideways the head must shoot off to the left (or right).

```
public GameObject RagdollBody;

HingeJoint2D joint;
bool cut = false;

Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    joint = GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Blade" && !cut)
    {
        joint.enabled = false;
        cut = true;

        rb.AddForce(-RagdollBody.transform.forward * 500);
    }
}
```

I watched a video that used -transform so it will shoot in the oppersite direction which is what i want. As the head is always 0,0,0 rotation, i need to get it from the parent but it still doesnt add any force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `transform.forward`, which represents the Z axis, or "inwards" if you will, in a 2d game.

If you want to add force upwards (relative to its orientation), i suggest trying this instead

```
rb.AddForce(RagdollBody.transform.up * 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be possible that you need to be using "AddRelativeForce" instead of "AddForce" on the last line there?

If this script is placed on the head you're launching you could try:

```
public GameObject RagdollBody;

HingeJoint2D joint;
bool cut = false;

Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    joint = GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Blade" && !cut)
    {
        joint.enabled = false;
        cut = true;

        rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.up * 500);

    }
}
```

or you could get the 2d rigid body all in the one line (only to save lines):

```
public GameObject RagdollBody;

    HingeJoint2D joint;
    bool cut = false;



    void Start()
    {
        joint = GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Blade" && !cut)
        {
            joint.enabled = false;
            cut = true;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddRelativeForce(Vector2.up * 500);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like in this case the force is pretty much the same but ill use relative anyway as in the final game it will be moving alot